# Where finite-state machine code belong in µC?

Tags: microcontroller, state-machines

When I learned about micrcontrollers, teachers taught me to always end the code with `while(1);` with no code inside that loop.

This was to be sure that the software get "stuck" to keep interruption working. When I asked them if it was possible to put some code in this infinite loop, they told me it was a bad idea. Knowing that, I now try my best to keep this loop empty.

I now need to implement a finite state machine in a microcontroller. At first view, it seems that that code belong in this loop. That makes coding easier.

Is that a good idea? What are the pros and cons?

---

This is what I plan to do :

```
void main(void)
{
    // init phase

 while(1)
 {
    switch(current_State)
    {
    case 1:
        if(...)
        {
            current_State = 2;
        }
        else(...)
        {
            current_State = 3;
        }
        else
            current_State = 4;
        break;

    case 2:
        if(...)
        {
            current_State = 3;
        }
        else(...)
        {
            current_State = 1;
        }
        else
            current_State = 5;
        break;
```

And this code goes on...

---

I ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44348147/6194206) in stackOverflow to get some more detail.

Comment: Please can you add a short example FSM listing so everyone's sure they're answering on the right thing. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM I briefly show what I plan to do.

Comment: Thanks. Explains my confusion: your question says 'always end the code with while(1);' but it starts with a 'while (1)'. Unless you're talking about a later 'while (1);' that isn't shown...?

Comment: @TonyM No, the 'while(1)' shown is the final one. But according to my teacher, this 'while(1)' shouldn't contain any code

Comment: Saying that having code in the `while (1)` is a bad idea seems a bit too generic to me. Sometimes it is useful, sometimes it is not, it entirely depends on the problem you need to solve. Your code looks good to me, another approach would be to put it into an interrupt called say at 1 kHz, if you need it timed but again, it depends.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes, I thought about the Timer solution. But unfortunately, every timers on the chip are already use :(

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the type of application that you are trying to build? I always put my program within the While(1)-loop, everything before this loop is just initialize of execute commands that just need to run once before the loop is entered. It is possible though to make a finite state machine where the code isn't placed inside the While-loop. Because you let the MCU jump to another state and thereby the MCU cannot get stuck in the while-loop. Look for example at Arduino: they recommand to place all the code in a while(1)-loop and initalisation stuff in the setup-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of how you handle this depends completely how the control scheme of the micro controller is meant to work. I see two normal scenarios.

**A.** If the control stream is one that "runs to completion" and wait for a power cycle or reset cycle restart then the appropriate ending is the "while(1)".

**B.** If the control stream is one in which the job "runs continuously" until terminated in a reset or power cycle then the appropriate design is to have the code include the FSM with its state variables be active within a "while(1) {}" construction. Note that often the best implementation of the FSM is as a switch statement with cases that correspond to each value of the state variable.

The simplest devices may be able to be managed using a single FSM. Most more complex systems will have multiple FSMs implemented as switch/cases inside of a subroutine. The main forever "while(1) {}" construction would have a sequence of calls to each of the FSM state machine subroutines. Sometimes one or more timer or I/O interrupts will also operate FSMs in the foreground over the main construction.

Answer (score 4):

I am working in automotive industry.

You often see such endless loops in situations where the CPU should reset - just like this:

```
if(some_error_occurred)
{
    while(1);
}
```

Car electronics have a so-called watchdog. The CPU must send a signal to the watchdog every few millieseconds. Otherwise the watchdog will reset the CPU.

Because the CPU is stuck in the endless loop in the example above the signal is no longer sent and the CPU is reset.

However normally 99% of all CPUs in automotive industry do not have a "regular" end. This means the whole code of the CPU could be written the following way:

```
initialize_cpu();
perform_initial_actions();
while(1)
{
    perform_cyclic_actions_endlessly();
}
```

Because there is no "end" of the program a `while` loop at the "end" of the program cannot exist.